# npm publish component with css and font

Tags: node.js, angular, fonts, npm, webpack

I want to publish an angular 2 component on NPM. This component use css which refer to some fonts. As far as publishing `.ts` files I can do that. But I'm lost concerning the css and the fonts.

I have :

```
despotic-turtle.component.ts
despotic-turtle.component.css
fonts/font.ttf .svg ...
```

and I have in my css this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'despotic-turtle';
  src:  url('despotic-turtle/fonts/font.eot?ggipqk');
  /* ....*/
}
```

I can't leave the css and fonts as is, so what can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`css`, `fonts` and `html` will be included in your `npm publish`.

The issue you'll encounter will be that the referenced css will not be found unless you add `moduleId` in `@Component`:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id
})
```

Note that you'll have to compile using commonjs to make this work.

Also, you shouldn't publish the `.ts` files to npm, the only files you should publish are `index.js` and `your-component.js` + `your-component.css` + `your-component.html`, `.d.ts` files and `font` files.

Keep in mind that npm is used to publish transpilled files only, when you import a library, you should not have to compile it (check `@angular` libraries, there's no ts in their libraries).

Comment: Yes you have to compile those files but you have to not add them in the publish (add *.ts to your .npmignore file). Your fonts will not be found, that's 100% sure, the only way to fix this is by using a cdn or host the file by your own to add it using an url.

Comment: Problem is that `moduleId` has been added to the `Component` decorator to fix this issue, but it's not here for css files (where you need your fonts).
One way would be to import the font using `url("/node_modules/......")` but I guess you already know it and don't want to do it because meh, it's ugly ! Unfortunately I don't think there's a solution for your issue except cdn storage. Every component libraries are using cdn and that's why.